# How to estimate the qubit frequency from a two-frequency Ramsey experiment?

Tags: quantum-state, decoherence

In a two-frequency Ramsey experiment, we obtain two Ramsey sequences from $f_d-\delta$ and $f_d+\delta$, where $f_d$ is the current drive frequency and $\delta$ is some detuning. We then estimate frequencies $f_-$ and $f_+$ (among other things such as $T_2^*$) from the two damping oscillations. The software package I am using claims that

$$
f_q=f_d+\frac{f_-^2-f_+^2}{4\delta}
$$

where $f_q$ is the qubit frequency that the drive frequency should be updated to. I understand the difference between $f_-$ and $f_+$ tells whether $f_d$ is behind or ahead of $f_q$. But how do we end up with this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drive a qubit off-resonantly, the [Rabi rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabi_cycle#math_1), i.e. how quickly you're driving the transition, is given by square root of the sum of the square of the qubit frequency and the square of the detuning (how far off resonance you're driving). In math, if we were just driving at a drive frequency $f_d$, our transition rate would be $\sqrt{f_q^2 + (f_q-f_d)^2}$ since $f_q-f_d$ would be the detuning between our drive and the qubit frequency.

Now if we instead drive at $f_d - \delta, f_d+\delta$ and measure Rabi frequencies of $f_-, f_+$, then after a little manipulation we have

$f_-^2 = f_q^2 + (f_q-(f_d - \delta))^2$
$= 2f_q^2 -2f_q(f_d - \delta) + (f_d - \delta)^2$

$f_+^2 = f_q^2 + (f_q-(f_d + \delta))^2$
$= 2f_q^2 -2f_q(f_d + \delta) + (f_d + \delta)^2$

Then $f_-^2 - f_+^2 = 4f_q \delta - 4f_d\delta$ and after a little rearranging we get $f_q = f_d + \frac{f_-^2 - f_+^2}{4\delta}$

Comment: Why do we have $\omega_0=\omega_1=\omega_q$ here?